# How do I get players to Name a Horror?

Tags: gm-techniques, earthdawn

I'm running an Earthdawn campaign and the party's current adversary is an unNamed Horror.  In Earthdawn, Horrors fall somewhere between a demon in D&D and an Elder God in Cthulhu.  It's important that this one be unNamed, because without a Name, it can't really grow or change too much, and it knows it.  It's confined to garden variety evil.

I want to have the characters Name it, because that way when it does horrible heinous badness that it never would have been capable of without a Name, they'll know that they have some measure of guilt, since they made it possible.

I'm currently having it engage in distinctive behavior and take an particular interest in messing with one of the characters.  It's going to start doing things that will give the party a bad rep, as well.  I'm also giving them items/spells that will help them fight it, but only if they can use its Name.  Since it doesn't currently have one, they would have to Name it.

Can anyone come up with other ways I can get them to Name the horror?

Comment: Hi Aaron, and welcome to the site. Please check our [tour] if you haven't already! We don't generally do brainstorming questions here well - they fall under several points of [Questions to avoid asking](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). In this case: _every answer is equally valid_, and _your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers._ See the first paragraph of that link: we focus on practical, answerable problems, rather than chatty, open-ended questions, which are suited better to forums.

Comment: To others and Aaron: is there a specific answerable problem which can possibly have a correct answer behind this? Such as, what are the ways available to Name a horror (if it's a confined set of things), or something other than an open-ended request for help filling in a plot blank?

Comment: @doppelgreener I think it's asking for a list (strike one) of opinions (strike two), but is mistaken in needing one and open to frame challenges because of it. I think GMs with experience using unNamed Horrors can also help in a way closer to what's being asked if they stick to Good Subjective practices. I'm on the fence then, about whether it's OK; enough that I'm hesitant to VTC myself but wouldn't protest if it was put on hold.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Would it be appropriate to edit the question into a "can/should I?" instead of a "how do I?"

Comment: @BESW Maybe? My editorial spider-sense isn't getting tingled by this question properly for some reason. Sorry, I'm no help.

Comment: I was looking for techniques other GMs had used in the same kind of situation (enticing players to do something that is obviously a Bad Idea).  That's why I tagged it gm-techniques, a tag that is quite popular, and has many similar requests for advice.

Answer (score 6):

## You wait

Your players will name it, most likely.

If they don't, the Horror remains unNamed. That's fine! Nothing ever goes as planned.

Answer (score 1):

Involve NPCs.  The NPCs hire the heros to chase away the unNamed horror.  Because no one had actually seen it, the NPCs ask the victorious heroes what they saw.  "What would you call something like that?!"

Then let the PCs fight over naming rights.  :-D